# How to creata multiple radio button selection? HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, radio-group

I want to create, if user select single, they only can select one edge. But if they select group. they can multiple edge. Is it I need to use Jquery.

[image: Current Interface]

Currently, if I select single or group, it still have no different where I still cannot select multiple radio button. I want to select single is for one check, group is for multiple check. How to solve this?

This is my code.

```
<div id="controlForm" class="form-container">
    
    <label for="application_status">
      <b>PC Selection Single/Group Edge</b>
    </label></br>
    <div id="gender" class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item"  value="single"  name="single" id="single"> Single
          </div>
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item"  value="group"  name="group" id="group"> Group
          </div><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <label for="application_status">
      <b>Select Edge</b>
    </label></br>
    <div id="gender" class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item"  value="Edge1"  name="edge1" id="edge1"> Edge 1
          </div>
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item"  value="Edge2"  name="edge1" id="edge1"> Edge 2
          </div>
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="Edge3" name="edge1" id="edge1"> Edge 3
          </div></br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: As your radio button `name` are same you can select only one radio button at a time . Alternative give different name or use checkboxes .Also add jquery code which you have tried in your asked question.

Comment: This check box solution is probably the best way to solve your problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315107/enable-single-or-multiple-checkboxes-checked-based-on-radio-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use radio buttons, try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="controlForm" class="form-container">
    
    <label for="application_status">
      <b>PC Selection Single/Group Edge</b>
    </label></br>
    <div id="pcSelect" class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item"  value="single"  name="pc" id="single"> Single
          </div>
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item"  value="group"  name="pc" id="group"> Group
          </div><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <label for="application_status">
      <b>Select Edge</b>
    </label></br>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="column" id="edgeSelect" >
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item"  value="Edge1" id="edge1" data-waschecked="false"> Edge 1
          </div>
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item"  value="Edge2" id="edge2" data-waschecked="false"> Edge 2
          </div>
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="Edge3" id="edge3" data-waschecked="false"> Edge 3
          </div></br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=pc]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'single') {
        $("#edgeSelect input[type=radio]").attr('name', 'edge');
        $("#edgeSelect input[type=radio]").off()
    }
    else if (this.value == 'group') {
        $("#edgeSelect input[type=radio]").removeAttr('name');
        $("#edgeSelect input[type=radio]:not(:checked)").data('waschecked', false);
        $("#edgeSelect input[type=radio]:checked").data('waschecked', true);
        $("#edgeSelect input[type=radio]").on('click',  (e)=> {
          var $radio = $(e.target);

          // if this was previously checked
          if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
          {
            $radio.prop('checked', false);
            $radio.data('waschecked', false);
          }
          else {
            $radio.prop('checked', true);
            $radio.data('waschecked', true);
          }
              
        })
    }
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfxh8t7a/40/

Building off of the answer to the question ["How can I toggle radiobutton"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15105717/4157513), the above code takes the following approach:

1. Set "Single" and "Group" to the same name attribute value - thus only one of these can be selected.
2. If "Single" is selected, set the name attribute of all the Edge radio buttons to the same value. This utilizes the default behavior of radio buttons with the same name. Only one Edge button can be selected.
3. If "Group" is selected, remove the name attribute. This allows all Edge buttons to be selected. By using the radio toggle method mentioned in the answer above, you can toggle the radio buttons.

The following lines:

```
        $("#edgeSelect input[type=radio]:not(:checked)").data('waschecked', false);
        $("#edgeSelect input[type=radio]:checked").data('waschecked', true);
```

are there so that there are no odd inconsistencies when switching from "Single" to "Group".

Answer (score 0):

instead of the radios, it would be more appropriate to consider input checkboxes. they are meant to be used with multiple options.

and if you want to style the checkboxes to look like the radios, you can make it using pure CSS:

```css
:root {
  --form-control-color: #0970e6;
  --form-control-disabled: #959495;
  --current-color: #adadad;
  --font-size: 1.5em;
  --transition-time: 120ms;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.form-control {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-weight);
  line-height: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1em auto;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.form-control + .form-control {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.form-control--disabled {
  color: var(--form-control-disabled);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  /* add if not using autoprefixer */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* remove most all native input styles */
  appearance: none;
  /* iOS < 15 */
  background-color: var(--form-background);
  /* not removed via appearance */
  margin: 0.1em 0 0;

  font: inherit;
  color: var(--current-color);
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 0.05em solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-0.075em);
  transition: var(--transition-time) background ease-in-out;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: var(--form-control-color);
}

input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 0.25em;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: var(--transition-time) transform ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: inset 1em 1em white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  transform: scale(1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled {
  --form-control-color: var(--form-control-disabled);

  color: var(--form-control-disabled);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label class="form-control">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
    I'm baby jianbing normcore schlitz
  </label>
  <label class="form-control">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-checked" checked />
    Gochujang williamsburg wolf 8-bit
  </label>
  <label class="form-control form-control--disabled">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-disabled-checked" checked disabled />
    Palo santo tonx quinoa shabby chic
  </label>
  <label class="form-control form-control--disabled">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-disabled" disabled />
    Copper mug pork belly cliche
  </label>
</form>
```

although, you can create a dynamic component with javascript that renders checkboxes or radios based on the condition you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

use reactive forms and give the formControlName to desired radio button. If select one all the other radio buttons with same formcontrolName will be selected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).